# How to reinstall all the network manager stuff I removed?

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, internet, 22.04

I had a problem with the Bluetooth headset and I thought that if I uninstalled and reinstalled the Bluetooth files, maybe it would solve the problem, but by the way, I think I accidentally removed the Network Manager files as well.

I can't install anything because there is no internet connection.

I tried all the codes I found on the internet but it didn't help because some of the files were missing.

Currently the computer has neither wifi nor network connection.
I can't reinstall because the computer doesn't see the USB device either.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What were the exact files you removed?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Lubuntu) libkf5networkmanagerqt6, network-manager-gnome, network-manager, network-manager-pptp and so many things.

Comment: Looks like for sure you removed all the network manger stuff. This info needs to be in the question and you might consider changing the title and rewording the question. What the question should be is how to reinstall all the network manager stuff you removed. If it was me I would be doing a reinstall of the entire OS since you have removed your terms so many other things.

Comment: That's the problem anyway.  Does not detect USB and CD-ROM.  Otherwise I would reinstall anyway and not look for solution to this problem here.

Comment: If setting the BIOS to boot from DVD or USB is not working that is a hardware issue, not an OS issue.

Comment: You should troubleshoot why you aren't able to boot from external media something unrelated and independent of the installed OS, if any.